# how to convert value one format into the another format?

Tags: iphone, ios

This is my Button method. When I press the button it's value is every time increment one & display into Label. Then it's reach 6 then convert like 1.0 , 7 = 1.1, 8 = 1.2  , 12 like 2.0 like cricket over format.

How can I do that?

```
-(void)OneNoBTNPressedMethod
{
    // LBL it's my label & display the text

    NSString * overStorage = LBL.text;

    // perform the addition operation

    CalcOperation operation;

    operation = Plus;

    //add one every time when we press the button

    NSString * overOneBTNStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"];
    NSString *overVal = overOneBTNStr;

    LBL.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%qi",[overVal longLongValue]+[overStorage longLongValue]];
}
```

Thanx in advance..

Comment: your count starts with 0.1 or 1?

Comment: @PratyushaTerli counter start with 1. thanks for your response.

Comment: So like: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.0 (for 6), 1.1 (for 7), 1.2 (for 8), 1.3 (for 9), 1.4 (for 10), 1.5 (for 11), 2.0 (for 12)? Maybe I am missing something but what is "cricket over format?"

Comment: @Firo ya,it's same like that....

Comment: Check my solution its work for you.. sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me. Hope it works for you as well. Assuming your LBL contains "1" as initial text. hope it helps

```
- OneNoBTNPressedMethod {
   NSString *str = LBL.text;
   NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
   if ([arr count] == 1) {
       if ([LBL.text intValue] >= 5) {
           LBL.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.%i",0,0];
       } else {
           LBL.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[LBL.text intValue] + 1];
       }
   } else if ([arr count] == 2) {
       if ([[arr objectAtIndex:1] intValue] >= 5) {
          int left = [[arr objectAtIndex:0] intValue] + 1;
          LBL.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.%i",left,0];
       } else {
           LBL.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.%i",[[arr objectAtIndex:0] intValue],[[arr objectAtIndex:1] intValue] + 1];
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: thank u so much, it's near to my problem. my label string is null at starting time & my first value is like 1.0 not 0.0 but i understand the scenario. thanx a lot......

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic

```
Let `int num` is count
Then

numBeforeDecimal = num/6;
numAfterDecimal = num%6;
```

Concatenate both number

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d.%d",numBeforeDecimal,numAfterDecimal];
```